# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null

Tags: java, mvc, spring, jdbc

Ao fazer uma consulta em uma classe dao, aparece o seguinte erro:

**meu spring-context.xml é:**

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="br.com.softwarescomerciais.os.interceptor.AutorizadorInterceptor"></bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.101.178/sc"/>
    <property name="username" value="sfilho"/>
    <property name="password" value="123"/>
</bean>
```

**minha classe dao:**

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

public boolean existe(Usuario usuario) {
    if (usuario == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usuário não deve ser nulo");
    } 

    String sql = "select NOME from USUARIOS where NOME = :NOME and SENHA = :SENHA";

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource); 
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parametros.put("NOME", usuario.getNome());
    parametros.put("SENHA", usuario.getSenha());

    SqlRowSet srs = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sql, parametros);

    boolean existe = srs.next();
    return existe;
}
```

**erro:**

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
>
> type Exception report
>
> message Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:943)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null
>   org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
>   org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:89)
>   br.com.softwarescomerciais.os.dao.UsuarioDao.existe(UsuarioDao.java:27)
>   br.com.softwarescomerciais.os.controller.LoginController.efetuaLogin(LoginController.java:34)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:748)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:833)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)

Comment: Você carregou o seu spring-context.xml corretamente em alguma das suas classes de configuração?

Comment: Como assim carregou?, desculpa sou novo com spring.